# Java: AWT Label not showing up

Tags: java, label, awt, filereader

Pretty straightforward issue. My Java AWT (not Swing) label is simply not showing up. Most of the following code isn't even being used (for debugging this issue).

Just a note: this is within a Frame's constructor (and yes I have added several other panels and such that work just fine). Secondly, the frame's layout has been set to `null`.

I'm stumped.

```
File inf = new File("instructions.txt");
        Label ilb;
        if(inf.exists())
        {
            Log.v("Loading instructions");

            try
            {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inf);
                byte[] insb = new byte[65535];
                fis.read(insb);
                fis.close();
                String inst = new String(insb);
                ilb = new Label("test", Label.LEFT);
                File fntfile = new File("font/pf_tempesta_seven.ttf");
                Font infnt = null;
                try {
                    FileInputStream ffis = new FileInputStream(fntfile);
                    infnt = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, ffis);
                    ffis.close();
                } catch (FontFormatException e) {
                    Log.e("Could not format LCD font!", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Could not read LCD font file!", e);
                }

                if(infnt == null)
                    infnt = new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, 8);
                else
                    infnt = infnt.deriveFont(8.0f);

                //ilb.setFont(infnt);
                //ilb.setForeground(new Color(123, 123, 123));

                //ilb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 400));
                //ilb.setSize(350, 400);

                //ilb.setLocation(580, 190);

                Log.d("adding label");
                add(ilb);

            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("Could not read instructions!", e);
            }
        }else
            Log.w("Instructions file not found!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JBNizet suggested, `null` layouts don't work with all AWT components.

I was thrown off since my `Panel`s were positioned just fine with a `null` layout on my `Frame`, whereas Labels *require* a basic layout in order to display. I was tempted to go as far as saying all other components had the same 'feature', but another part of my code proved that point wrong:

```
// Load Image
        Log.v("Loading header image");
        _iBG = new ImageIcon("img/hpcount_top_bg.png").getImage();

        // Set size
        setSize(1024, 152);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 152));

        // Set position
        setLocation(0, 0);

        // Set visible
        setVisible(true);

        // Set layout
        setLayout(null);

        // Add children
        add(new Exit()); // Exit extends java.awt.Button
```

The above code (which is located within the constructor of a class extending `java.awt.Panel`) works perfectly.

My workaround is to put the label inside another `Panel` with a layout (messy, but it works) and position that panel within the `Frame` absolutely to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

1) for todays GUI use Swing `JComponents` (starts with `J`) rather than prehistoric `AWT Label`

2) for your issue could be better use [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) with method `append()`

3) you have got issues with [Concurency (in Swing)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) `AWT / Swing` is single threaded and all output to the GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater`

4) for better help sooner you have edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I thought I had a comment in there about swing, but I guess I left it out. **I have it AWT for a reason. No swing.**

Comment: And no, it's not a concurrency issue. That has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Also, I prefer to format my questions just like I have it. I preferred to have the dead code in there to see if it's another issue that I'm not focusing on, just in case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: To expand on the concurrency statement: I have no other threads running, and this code is clearly run in that window's schedule.

Comment: Also, while AWT's Label might be "prehistoric", it is also the only Label that is supported across all platforms for all devices. Swing is a convenience library located within javax (which should have been your first hint) that provides an extended UI based solely on layouts and pre-packaged themes. This is exactly what I was trying to get *away* from, so excuse me for using basic controls, *especially* when I know exactly which computer/OS it will be run on. Using AWT !== idiocy.

Comment: I'd suggest for using ATW component if is there real important reason, e.g. OpenGL, OpenCV, CAD, CAM and HD multimedia API's

Comment: I considered OpenGL; however it seemed overkill for this situation. It's just basic `Image` objects and custom fonts, so I kept it within the bounds of `paint()` overrides.

Comment: nobody here told you that you're something ***, nor that AWT equals ***, maybe you posted here *** question, post to the public forum, where on second side are only volunteers, then 102,5599 pct of your talking about your too hot head, sorry then to hard get good answer

Comment: On top of that making no sense, I'm not accepting your answer not because you're opposing me, but because the answer is clearly not fit for the OP. I clearly said AWT, and instead you tried to point me to Swing. Secondly, your argument for concurrency doesn't apply. TextArea for AWT *and* swing both draw borders, which do not mesh well with the design of the GUI; further, if you read the code in the OP, `append()` is clearly unnecessary. I appreciate the suggestion for concise code, but as I said before, the dead code could have been relevant to a solution.